# What is $f(D)$ if $f(z)=\frac{z+1}{z-1}$ and $D=\{z\in\mathbb C\mid \bar z=-z \}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I have $$\mathcal D=\{z\in\mathbb C\mid \bar z=-z \}$$ 
and \begin{align*}f:\mathbb C\setminus \{1\}&\longrightarrow \mathbb C\setminus \{1\}\\ z&\longmapsto \frac{z+1}{z-1}.\end{align*}

I have to find $f(\mathcal D)$. I set $z=iy\in \mathcal D$ and I get
$$f(iy)=\frac{1-y^2}{1+y^2}+i\frac{2y}{1+y^2}.$$

I know that if $y=\tan(\frac{\theta}{2})$ with $\theta\in]-\pi,\pi[$
$$\frac{1-y^2}{1+y^2}+i\frac{2y}{1+y^2}=\cos(\theta)+i\sin \theta$$

and thus $f(\mathcal D)= C_1(0)$ the circle of center $0$ and radius $1$, but I'm not sure I can do like that, and If it's right, why does it really work ?

Comment: I think you made a mistake with your result for $f(iy)$ , because when you input $y=0$ you get $f(0)=1$ , whereas $f(0)=-1$.

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistake in the $f(iy)$ formula . It should be $f(iy)=\frac{y^2-1}{1+y^2}-i\frac{2y}{1+y^2} $ and consequently for $y= \tan (\frac{\theta}{2} ) $  you get $f(iy)=-\cos (\theta) - i \sin (\theta) $ , which of course is also a point from a circle $C_1(0) $

So far you've shown that $f(D) \subset C_1(0) $

In order to get the equality of sets you need to show the oposite inclusion.